# Add custom action:@selector to UISwitch on TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, action, selector, uiswitch

I have TableCellViewController for managing cells in my UITableView. Each cell has a label na UISwitch (dictTypeSwitch). A want to assign method to switch events so I can save the state of button.

So far I've done this:

assign setState function to object:

```
[cell.dictTypeSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

function for handling event:

```
- (void)setState:(id)sender {
    BOOL state = [sender isOn];
    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    NSLog(rez);
}
```

From sender I get UISwitch object from which I can get state.

So far everything is ok.

But if I want to save the state of UISwitch, I have to get rowIndex for this cell.
How can I achieve this?

```
The cells are made inside function cellForRowAtIndexPath. Se the code bellow:

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DictionariesTableCellViewController";
    DictionariesTableCellViewController *cell = (DictionariesTableCellViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DictionariesTableCellViewController" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (DictionariesTableCellViewController *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.dictTypeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row - %i",indexPath.row];
    [cell.dictTypeSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the UISwitch's [`.tag` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) to store an arbitrary integer. This can be set to the row index.

If it is possible to find the UITableViewCell from UISwitch's parent, you could get the index path with

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [theTableView indexPathForCell:theCell];
```